# How can i return value from generic Func<>

Tags: c#, generics, methods, delegates, func

How can i provide return value according by followed sample? I want to use this function like this `MyMethod(model=> model.Id)`

```
public T MyMethod(Func<T> item)
{
    return ??
}
```

Comment: The usage implies a signature with a parameter of something like `Func<T, object>`.  What is it you are actually trying to do?

Comment: No, i have been already tried.

Comment: What does `MyMethod` suppose to do? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It is impossible to answer because it is unclear what you need. Any answer has to guess what you want. Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

```
public TS MyMethod<T,TS>(T item,Func<T,TS> selector)
{
    return selector(item);
}
```

Comment: Ivan thaks for your aid but i did not used this method.